# Files and Folder view option in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

By default all the files and folders are viewed as `Tiles` format in Windows XP.

I want to change the folders and files view option to:

```
 View -> Details
 Arrange Icons By -> Show in Groups
 Arrange Icons By -> Types
```

This setting should be applied to entire file system how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to an example folder. Apply the view settings that you wish. Then go to Tool > Folder Options. Select the View tab. Add any additional setting from the list. Then click Apply to Folders.

*This is probably you the closest you can get without 3rd party apps.*